# Custom Service and AltBeacon

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

and sorry for my english.
i'm working with iBeacon, and to do that, i'm using [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html).
It's great and work perfectly, but now i need your help.

I have a thread that start and send information when a certain iBeacon enter in the region, and stop when the iBeacon leave the region.
The problem is that when i kill the app, the thread die.
I think about a Service, but i discover that using BootstrapNotifier is impossible to use another custom Service.

So, have you any ideas about how accomplish this task?
Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i solved it in another way.
I'm using my custom Service and no more implement BootstrapNotifier in Application.

Here is my code, if someone need it.

```
public class BeaconDetector extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {

private static final String TAG = "BeaconDetector";

private BeaconUtility.BeaconObject beaconObject;

private Context getServiceCtx(){
    return BeaconDetector.this;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IMLog.e(TAG, "Created.");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    IMLog.e(TAG, "Start.");

    beaconObject = BeaconUtility.instantiateBeaconManager(this);
    beaconObject.beaconManager.bind(this);

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    IMLog.e(TAG, "Destroy.");
    beaconObject.beaconManager.unbind(this);
}


@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    IMLog.e(TAG, "Connected.");

    beaconObject.beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
            // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
            // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
            IMLog.e(TAG, "did enter region.");
            Sender.getInstance(getServiceCtx()).startSender();
        }

        @Override
        public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
            IMLog.e(TAG, "did exit region.");
            if (Sender.getInstance(getServiceCtx()).isAlive()) {
                Sender.getInstance(getServiceCtx()).stopSender();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
            IMLog.e(TAG, "did enter region.");
        }
    });

    try {
        beaconObject.beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(BeaconUtility.getMonitoringRegion());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        IMLog.e(TAG, "Remote Exception.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Glad you solved it!  This is a better approach than using the RegionBootstrap, which is really designed for use in an `Application` class.